# Hide specific image in class

Tags: php, jquery

I need to hide and run a delete script when a user clicks on an image.

**Display script:**

```
<?php
echo '<img src="../uploads/foto/clanky/' . $file . '" id="' . $id . '" class="img_edit">';
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( ".img_edit img" ).click(function() {
        var className = $('.img_edit').attr('id');
        $(this.id).hide( "slow", function() {

        });
        $.post("delete.php?id="+className);
    });
</script>
```

But it's still doesn't work.

Comment: "*It is not working*" is not useful. Please explain, if you get an error message (if so, which one) or if the results differ from your expectation (if so, how).

Comment: className = .attr('id') is very confusing.

Comment: For starters, `$( ".img_edit img" )` is wrong, `.img_edit` is the image.

Comment: dont be so rude friends its a newb here well man give us your proper coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector doesn't need the `img` part, and if anything the `img` part should be prepended to `.img_edit` because the `img` element is not a **child** of the `img_edit` class, it is an element that **has** that class (`img.img_edit` would be fine, but not necessary here):

```
$('.img_edit').click(function() {
```

You can get the id like this:

```
var className = $(this).attr('id');
```

You should remove the `.id` part of your `hide` call:

```
$(this).hide("slow");
```

**Side note:** You'd be better off putting your id in a data attribute rather than an id, but it shouldn't affect your results unless you end up getting duplicate IDs.

**Result:**

```
$( ".img_edit" ).click(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).hide("slow");
    $.post("delete.php?id=" + className);
});
```